# Does analytic completion commute with norm/valuation?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, field-theory, valuation-theory

Let $k$ be a field with a norm $|\cdot|$ and $\hat{k}$ its completion regarding this norm (with induced norm). We denote by $|k| \subseteq \mathbb R$ the values of the norm in $\mathbb R$. The question is:

> Is the (analytic) closure $\overline{|k|}$ of $|k|$ in $\mathbb R$ equal to $|\hat k|$?

If no, does this hold for non-archimedian norms, i.e. if the norm comes from a valuation?

It is clear that $|\hat k| \subseteq \overline{|k|}$ and equality holds for discrete norms, the question is now given a sequence in $k$ whose norm converges, can we construct a Cauchy-sequence in $k$ with the same norm-limit.

An idea of a counter-example would be
$k=\mathbb R(X_1, X_2, \dots)$ the quotient-field over the polynomial ring with countably many variables and valuation
$$\nu(X_i)=\lambda_i \in \mathbb Q \text{ with } 1<\lambda_1< \lambda_2 < \dots \text{ and } \lim \lambda_i =\sqrt{42}$$
but I don't see how to prohibit a Cauchy-sequence with the same norm or to construct such one (both should be sufficient for either a proof or refute the statement for valuations). If you prefer you can also choose $(\lambda_i)$ to be a decreasing sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $k=\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p$ (the algebraic closure of the field of $p$-adic numbers), $|k|=|\hat{k}|=p^{\mathbb{Q}}\cup\{0\}$. If $\overline{|k|}$ means usual "topologic" closure of $|k|$ (in $\mathbb{R}$), then $\overline{|k|}=\mathbb{R}_{\geqslant 0}$. Does this answer the question?

Comment: Yes, but I can't see why $|\hat{k}|=|k|$ holds.

Comment: If $x_n\to x$ and $x\neq 0$, there is $m$ such that $|x_n-x|<|x|$ for all $n\geqslant m$. In non-archimedian case the latter implies $|x_n|=|x|$ for all $n\geqslant m$.

Comment: (appears to be already noted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103661/value-groups-of-an-archimedean-field-and-its-completion-coincide))

Comment: Ok, thanks. Somehow I tried to show your comment but the case $x =0$ convinced me not to look further to this direction. Well, seems that was a mistake on my side.

Comment: @ctst The elements of $\mathbb{C}_p = \hat{k}$ are of the form $\sum_{j=1}^\infty c_j=\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j p^{b_j}$ with $c_j \in \overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}, |c_{j+1}| > |c_j| \to 0$ ie. $b_j < b_{j+1} \to \infty \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $a_j \in \overline{\mathbb{Z}_p}^\times$